# MySQL fulltext MATCH AGAINST not working for plurals

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to get a simple fulltext search working in mySQL but am having some issues with plurals.

I do believe I am hitting **the 50% rule**.

I do not believe I am using **stop words**.

I'm running a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product_detail WHERE MATCH(product_detail.title, product_detail.content) AGAINST('rake' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

- 22 results

Then I run:

```
SELECT * FROM product_detail WHERE MATCH(product_detail.title, product_detail.content) AGAINST('rakes' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

- 0 results

A search for 'a rake' or 'the rake' returns all 22 results, but 'rakes', 'raker', 'raked' returns zero. I'm just running these queries in phpMyAdmin so nothing else is interfering.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Why don't you try to confirm your hypothesis by querying ... like '%rakes%'? If you get more than 50% of the records back, then you know that you have hit the limit. If there are no redords found, then you know that your dataset does not contain the requested data.

Comment: That would be a good method to check something like this. I should have said that I am all but positive I'm not hitting the max because of my understanding and knowledge of this website, the amount and variety of products etc. There are thousands of products and rake really isn't going to be that common. At most 1-2%. Also rake was just an example, I've tried with many others.

Answer (score 0):

A BOOLEAN search doesn't use the 50% rule.

If "rake" is stored in your FULLTEXT column, then a FULLTEXT search with "rake", "a rake", and "the rake" will all return that row because the search values all contain the word "rake". With a NATURAL LANGUAGE (not BOOLEAN) search, when searching for "the rake", entries that include both "the" and "rake" will have a higher relevance value than rows with just "rake".

However, "rakes", "raker", and "raked" do not have the word "rake" in them. FULLTEXT searches are word searches, and "rakes" does not match "rake".

You can use a wildcard in a BOOLEAN search. Searching for "rake*" would return rows with "rake", "rakes", and "raked", etc., but you cannot search for "rakes" or "raked" and get "rake".